# "AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'" error while trying to create lambda function using boto3 python 3.7 in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is the function code which I am using to create lambda function locally using boto3 SDK in VSCode. I have already installed and setup boto3 SDK in the VSCode

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('lambda')

response = client.create_function(
Code={
},
Description='Test LambdaFunction using boto3 SDK',
FunctionName='TestLambda',
# is of the form of the name of your source file and then name of your function handler
Handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
MemorySize=128,
Publish=True,
# replace with the actual arn of the execution role you created
Role='arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/TestRole',
Runtime='python3.7',
Timeout=15,
VpcConfig={
    'SubnetIds': [
        'subnet-xxxxxx',
        'subnet-xxxxxx'
    ],
    'SecurityGroupIds': [
        'sg-xxxxx66',
    ],
    'VpcId': 'vpc-xxxxx'
  },
)
```

print(response)

---

Can anyone help me in what mistake I am doing to create lambda function using boto3 SDK?

Comment: Your client creation looks correct to me; the only thing I could think of is that you have an outdated version of boto3 -- worth checking. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution might be

1. You are having, another file like boto3.py in same directory or project's working directory. Delete this file.
2. As you are running it on lambda there can be a chance that filename for the code might be one of built-in python module.
   E.g. copy is built-in python module. Name copy.py for file may cause import issue, as this builtin module is used somewhere in boto3.
   Change the filename.